# How to use divides and for_each?

Tags: c++, foreach, std, elementwise-operations

I have:

```
vector<double> ved1 = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
vector<double> ved2 = { 11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 };
vector<double> ved3(10);
```

and I want to have ved3=ved3/2  but I can't get it correctly, the result is 2/ved3;
How to use divides?

```
transform(ved1.begin(), ved1.end(), ved2.begin(), ved3.begin(), plus<double>());
transform(ved3.begin(), ved3.end(), ved3.begin(), bind1st(divides<double>(),2));`
```

I want cos(ved2), but I cannot get it. What's wrong with my code?

```
double cos_1(double x) { return cos(x); }
for_each(ved2.begin(), ved2.end(), cos_1);
```

Comment: how about using lambda? `transform(ved3.begin(), ved3.end(), ved3.begin(), [](double d){return d / 2;}));`?

Comment: This appears to be two different questions. Ask one question per question.

Comment: Maybe you can try [`valarray`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray). Though `valarray` provides very limited functionality, but if you only use the functionality it provides, you'll find it very convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind1st` will bind `2` to the 1st argument of `divides`, and then `transform` will supply each element of `ved3` to `divides` as the second argument. So the result will be `divides(2, ved3[0])`, `divides(2, ved3[1])` and so on.

If you want to calculate `divides(ved3[...], 2)` instead, use `bind2nd(divides<double>(),  2)`. This way, `2` will be bound to the second argument, leaving the first one vacant for `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to use `std::for_each` to apply a cosine elementwise

[`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) does not fill some output; or necessarily change the input container/range. It just applies an invocable object to each element of a range. If the function has no "side effects" - than the `for_each` would be useless. Specifically, in your case - you're computing the cosine of each value, but not doing anything with it.

If you want to change the values in-place, you'll need to specifically do that:

```
void apply_cos(double& x) { x = std::cos(x); }

// ...

for_each(ved2.begin(), ved2.end(), apply_cos);
```

or using a lambda expression:

```
for_each(ved2.begin(), ved2.end(), [](double& x) { x = cos(x); });
```

Note the use of a **reference** input to the function rather than a **value**: `double& x`, not `double x`. That means that when you change `x` in `apply_cos()`, the value in the input range to `std::for_each` changes.